# Add "Content" for the "empty" div

Tags: html, css

I have to apply some text only if the div does not have any content in it. I have tried following CSS but does not seems to work:

```
.uploadQueue:empty(:before){content:"Select files to upload.";color:#ccc; font-size:14px;}
.uploadQueue:empty{content:"Select files to upload.";color:#ccc; font-size:14px;}
.uploadQueue:before(:empty){content:"Select files to upload.";color:#ccc;font-size:14px;}
```

None of the above seems to work. The following css works, but what I want is to apply this only for the "empty" div.

```
.uploadQueue:before{content:"Select files to upload."; color:#ccc; font-size:14px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gauravgr/AD37D/1/

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to do here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to chain the pseudo-class with the pseudo-element selector:

```
.uploadQueue:empty::before {
    content:"Select files to upload."; color:#ccc; font-size:14px;
}
```

Bear in mind that the `:empty` selector requires the element contain nothing at all, including empty text-nodes.

Comment: That's perfect! I got it. Thanks @David.

Comment: That caveat pretty much ruins this for me with MVC. Rendering the view to add children if they exist requires. `<div></div>` unless I branch the cshtml to insert `<div />` if no children.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try using jquery.

```
    $('.uploadQueue').each(function(){
       if($(this).text()=='') $(this).text('Some Text');
       // if($(this).html() == '') $(this).html('<span>Some html</span>')  // check if div contains any HTML
    });
```

Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/AD37D/2/